# Faster rcnn code examples using keras and tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to implement faster rcnn from scratch using Keras . As a newbie , i wanted to understand whether there are any code examples which i can refer to build my own model . Most of the examples which I have found online are not explained properly .

Would appreciate if anyone can point me towards the right resource